# Stop Updating location from different View Controller

Tags: swift, xcode, location, locationmanager

I have implemented a code that starts updating user location then present a different view.

`self.manager.startUpdatingLocation(interval: 4)
 self.present(viewController, animated: true , completion: nil)`

then when I tried to stop updating location my app is still printing coordinates.

Is there any code to disable location manager from the whole app? Then if I want to start again I want to use same line of code

Things I tried :

```
 func stopLocation (){
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        self.manager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    }
}
```

`self.manager.stopUpdatingLocation()`

Comment: Make sure you are not creating multiple instance of manager.

Comment: I did actually make instance in the second view. If I don't do it it will show an error `found nil`

Comment: Create a class for both functionalities for starting and stopping.. and just call in whatever view controller you need it in viewdidload or viewdidappear and make sure you stop it in viewdiddisappear

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're creating a different copy of your manager/location manager for each view controller. You want a single object that both view controllers talk to to control your app's use of the location manager.

This is a good use case for the singleton design pattern. Make your Manager class a singleton, and then use that single instance to manage your location manager status.

The call might look like:

```
Manager.shared.stopUpdatingLocation()
```

You should be able to Google `Swift singleton pattern" to learn about it. There are dozens and dozens of code examples online.

Comment: it already a library that update location in the background mode. https://github.com/paleksandrs/APScheduledLocationManager is it possible to make a singleton from this ?

Comment: Probably, although glancing at it it is set up to notify a single delegate about location updates. You probably want it to notify the current front view controller, so you might need to change the delegate. It might take some refactoring to be able to do that.

Comment: Thanks. I'm struggling with the delegate and how to set it. If you can help me with the solution

Comment: That would  depend on how the `APScheduledLocationManager` framework is written, and I don't have time to dig into that.

Comment: It looks like the `APScheduledLocationManager` is written to take a delegate in it's initializer, and not allow you to change it. You will either need to refactor that class to make it so that you can change the delegate, or create an intermediate object that serves as the `APScheduledLocationManager`'s delegate and forwards the location updates to your view controller. Alternately, you could refactor the `APScheduledLocationManager ` class to broadcast a notification manager notification about location updates.

Comment: I initiate it in AppDelegate and control it from there. It works so far